# Where to find more of these puzzles?

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics

Examples:

> A packing company supplies storage boxes in three diﬀerent sizes: small,
>   medium, and large. All three types of box have the same ratio of width:length
>   and height:length. It is noted that:
>   A. Eight small boxes ﬁt neatly inside one medium box.
>   B. The length of the small box is the same as the height of the medium box.
>   C. The base area (i.e. width times length) of a large box is 9 times smaller
>   than the base area of the small box.
>   D. The lengths of all three boxes added together is 2.4 m.
>   E. The width of the medium box is twice the height of the small box.
>   What are the lengths of the three diﬀerent boxes?
>   What are the ratios of the width:height and width:length of the boxes?
>
> Freight transport on Titan is mostly by ship, with three types of ship called
>   pangs, quizzers, and roodles in common use. All three ships have the same
>   shape and design but diﬀer in size. The cargo capacity depends on the hold
>   volume, while the number of crew required is proportional to the surface area
>   of the deck. A quizzer and a roodle taken together have the same length as
>   two pangs, and the crew of a quizzer is just suﬃcient to provide crew for two
>   pangs and a roodle.
>   A fully loaded quizzer wishes to transfer all its cargo to smaller pangs and
>   roodles, while minimising the number of crew required for the resultant ﬂeet.
>   How many pangs and roodles are needed?
>   [Hint: Note that for objects of any shape the surface area is proportional to
>   the square of the object’s size, and the volume is proportional to the cube of
>   its size.]
>
> A forest is inhabited by three species of macaw which are all the same
>   shape but are di®erent sizes and colours. The food consumption of
>   each type is proportional to the square of its length. Given that
>   (a) A crimson macaw and a ruby macaw put together are twice as
>   long as a scarlet macaw
>   (b) A crimson macaw and a scarlet macaw put together eat as much
>   as a ruby macaw
>   (c) 2 crimson macaws and a scarlet macaw put together are 1 m long
>   determine the lengths of the three types of macaw.

I like these puzzles, and I want to practice them to get better at them (as I will be tested on similar puzzles), however, I can't seem to find any similar puzzles. These are the criteria:

- Preferably, it has the same form as the above ones, where a couple of different objects have different properties, and you have to puzzle to find a certain asked property.
- No advanced mathematics required, like in the puzzles.

That's basically it. These types of puzzles remind me of [this](http://www.stanford.edu/~laurik/fsmbook/examples/Einstein%27sPuzzle.html) famous puzzle, which was supposedly created by Einstein.

Comment: If you like them, you might like Mathematical Logic. It's symbol-heavy but some of the problems are similar.

Comment: Where did you get these problems from?

Comment: @CalvinLin Physics Aptitude Test, past papers